# How to structure a python project with ipython notebooks?

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, python-import

After looking at many answers here, I still dont understand how to structure a python project with imports...

Let's say my dir structure is

```
myproject
   utils
      tool1.py
   datasets
      create_bla_dataset.py
   research
      mynote.ipynb
```

now I import tool1 from create_bla_dataset.py with

```
# We are in create_bla_dataset.py 
from ..utils import tool1

... define how to create a dataset

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # demo the dataset
```

and I can run the file with

```
> cd <dir_contains_myproject>
> python -m myproject.datasets.create_bla_dataset
```

But now I want to import create_bla_dataset inside mynote.ipynb while opening mynote.ipynb with a jupyter notebook, but I have no idea how...

If I try `from ..datasets import create_bla_dataset`, I get `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

edit: I tried launching jupyter notebook from various directories but no luck, same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use IPython/Jupyter Notebooks you need take account that ipython server only see files from a root directory defined from where you launch the notebook instance. In this case, maybe you are launched directly the notebook file and not from the project root.

Also, you can use `__init__.py` files.

**Updated**: You can add a cell at top of the notebook.

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('..')))
```

Then, `myproject` is recognized as a package and you can import as is.

```
from myproject.datasets.create_bla_dataset import bar
bar()
>>> 'hi foo hi bar'
```

This is because relative import only work in packages and if you need use as package you need to add the path where is the package.

Comment: I tried launching jupyter notebook from various locations but no luck :(

Comment: You need launch the dashboard from `myproject`. Can you share a minimal example from a public URL?

Comment: I tried launching from 'myproject' too... What do you mean by sharing from a public URL? Thanks!

Comment: By public URL is that you can share a basic example and then I will download to test.

Comment: Ah I see, how's this? https://www.dropbox.com/s/76x6rm98g3g619q/myproject.zip?dl=0